# Test database wont use fixtures created inside feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I added selenium webdriver to my test setup to start writing some tests based on javascript. I added

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_max_wait_time = 5
    config.default_driver = :selenium
  end
```

to my rails helper which now look like this

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __dir__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require "rspec/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec", "support", "**", "*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_max_wait_time = 5
    config.default_driver = :selenium
  end
  
  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  # Include Factory Bot syntax methods
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  # Configure Database Cleaner
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

After these changes, my previous feature tests broke because now they do not use the fixtures created within the tests.

i.e **features/article_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "articles", type: :feature do
  before :each do
    create(:article, published: false)
    create(
      :article,
      name: "Published article",
      body_text: "Lorem ipsum",
      published_at: Time.now,
      published: true
    )
  end

  describe "article feature" do
    it "shows only published articles" do
      visit("/articles")
      expect(page).to have_css(".article-container", count: 1)
    end
  end
end
```

The tests are not running headless so I can follow along and see that no articles are present despite the creation within **article_spec.rb**. I assume the driver executes the tests using another server and/or another database but I'm not sure. In which case don't know how to change that or how to seed that database. You guys have any clue?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I'm using rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `around` hook for database cleaner with RSpec and Capybara because of the order the hooks get run in. If you're going to continue using database cleaner you need to be using closer to the recommended configuration - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

That being said, since Rails 5.1 assuming you're using a normal configuration (testing with local app, normal DB config, up to date rspec-rails, etc) you don't need to use database cleaner at all, just set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in your RSpec configuration, remove all references to database cleaner, and the DB connection should be safely shared between your tests and the app under test.

Comment: you're too good! Changed the database cleaner setup after the example you provided via the link and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Given the driver setup I have for feature tests do you know the easiest way to start running the tests headless?

Comment: @JonasFagerlund Specify the options to make Chrome headless in your driver registration - See https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb for examples